# Как правильно определить углы белого листа бумаги?

Tags: java, opencv

*Пытаюсь найти углы белого листа бумаги.*

*Четвёртый угол не там где он нужен.*

*Что не так?*

```
package com;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;  

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Loading the OpenCV core library  
        System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
        System.out.println("Версия OpenCV: " + Core.VERSION);
    
        String file = "images\\white3.png"; 
        Mat imageOriginal = Imgcodecs.imread(file);
 
        Mat imageOriginalResize = new Mat();
        Size minScaleSize = new Size(imageOriginal.width()/4, imageOriginal.height()/4);
        Imgproc.resize(imageOriginal, imageOriginalResize, minScaleSize , 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_AREA);
  
        Mat imageGray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imageOriginalResize, imageGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  
        Mat imageGaussianBlur = new Mat();
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageGray, imageGaussianBlur, new Size(3, 3), 3);
    
        Mat imageCanny = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(imageGaussianBlur, imageCanny, 120, 250, 3, true);
    
    
        MatOfPoint corners = new MatOfPoint();
        System.out.println("Поиск углов");
        Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(imageCanny, corners, 4, 0.01, 500);
    
        if (corners.toArray().length == 4) {
            System.out.println("Найденно углов: " + corners.toArray().length);
    
            Point[] cornerPoints = corners.toArray();
            Point tl = cornerPoints[3];
            Point br = cornerPoints[0];
    
    
            Rect rect = new Rect(tl, new Size(br.x, br.y));
            System.out.println("Будущий квадрат: " + rect);
    
            //Mat mat = new Mat(cornerpoints[0], cornerpoints[1], cornerpoints[2], cornerpoints[3]);
            // Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect();
    

            for (Point points : cornerPoints) {
                System.out.println(points);
                int pointXI = (int) points.x;
                String pointXS = Integer.toString(pointXI);
                int pointYI = (int) points.y;
                String pointYS = Integer.toString(pointYI);
        
                Imgproc.circle(imageOriginalResize, points, 5, new Scalar(0,0,255), 3);
                Imgproc.putText(imageOriginalResize, pointXS + " " + pointYS, 
                    new Point(points.x-20, points.y+20) , 1, 1, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
                // Imgproc.rectangle(imageOriginalResize, rect, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5);
                }
        
        }else {
            System.out.println("Углы не найдены");
        }
    
        HighGui.namedWindow( "Image original", HighGui.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        HighGui.imshow( "Image original", imageOriginalResize);

        HighGui.namedWindow( "Image Canny", HighGui.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        HighGui.imshow( "Image Canny", imageCanny);
    
        if (HighGui.waitKey(0) == 27) {

            HighGui.destroyAllWindows();
            imageOriginal.release();
            imageGray.release();
            imageGaussianBlur.release();
            imageCanny.release();
            imageOriginalResize.release();
        
        } else {
            HighGui.destroyAllWindows();
            imageOriginal.release();
            imageGray.release();
            imageGaussianBlur.release();
            imageCanny.release();
            imageOriginalResize.release();
        
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

[image: То что получилось]

Comment: Попробуйте искать не углы напрямую, а краевые линии, через преобразование Хафа. Затем найти пересечения этих линий.

Comment: Было бы не плохо если бы вы показали на примере)

Comment: Я уже весь интернет перерыл вот всё что имею по нахождению белого листа, ещё есть реализация через findContours но там если изображение чуть повёрнуто то невозможно очертить контуры.

Comment: Посмотрите пример: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/10/opencv-sudoku-solver-and-ocr/  там ищется рамка вокруг судоку.